# Ack for Spring Rabbit Mq Example

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am new to Rabbit MQ with Spring Boot Integration. I have taken a demo example from spring website. In the example i am sending the message from my Runner Class and receiving the same from my receiver class. But i need to send acknowledgement from my receiver class to sender class. Can someone tell me what is the procedure to do so. Below are my classes :

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    final static String queueName = "springRabbitQueue";

    @Bean
    Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    TopicExchange exchange() {
        return new TopicExchange("springRabbitQueueExchange");
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(queueName);
    }


    @Bean
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(queueName);
        container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        return container;
    }


    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Runner.java

```
@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
    private final Receiver receiver;
    private final ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    public Runner(Receiver receiver, RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Application.queueName, "Hello from Rabit MQ Demo!");
        receiver.getLatch().await(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(new ConfirmCallback(){

            @Override
            public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {

                System.out.println("confirm correlationData is : "+correlationData+"ack is : "+ ack);
            }

        });
        rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);

        context.close();
    }

}
```

Receiver.java

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public void receiveMessage(String message) {
            System.out.println("Received Demo<" + message + ">");
            latch.countDown();
        }

        public CountDownLatch getLatch() {
            return latch;
        }

}
```

Comment: you have already set it at `container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);`. Your listener is already set to auto acknowledge...

Comment: if i need to send manual ack from my Receiver class to Runner class, what should i do ?

Comment: Check all the AcknowledgeModes

Comment: do you have any sample project to send manual ack with Rabbit Mq and spring integration ?

Comment: No i do not have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood Messaging principles a bit. The `Sender` and `Receiver` are fully distinguished components and typically they don't know about each other.

One just place a message and get an acknowledge from the Broker that the message is there in the queue.

Receiver just get a message from queue and acknowledges Broker that message can be removed from the queue.

There is no connections between sender and received.

If you would like to implement something to notify sender that receiver has a message you should consider to use Request/Reply pattern: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#request-reply

More samples is here, BTW: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples